# How to remove td line-number and and line-content class from saved html page using beautiful soup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have saved a webpage html content via viewing source code. I have done it this way because I cannot connect to the webpage due to it being in a citrix environment. The problem I am having is that when I read the saved `html` file and use beautiful soup to read the content it has created an extra table element which has the actual html content in td elements.

I inspected this as at first I tried to simply use the `find_all` function to find the `h2` elements but it was an empty list. Instead I have had to go through first finding the `html`, `body`, `table` elements, then from there I am able to get all the `td` elements with the actual html content from the page in it like so;

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = open("C:\\Users\\m\Documents\common\\cramer.html")
content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
html = soup.find('html')
body = html.find('body')
table = body.find('table')
tds = table.find_all('td')
```

This produces;

```
[
 <td class="line-number" value="380"></td>,
 <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/tr&gt;</span></td>,
 <td class="line-number" value="381"></td>,
 <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/table&gt;</span></td>,
 <td class="line-number" value="382"></td>,
 <td class="line-content"><span class="html-tag">&lt;/div&gt;</span></td>,
 <td class="line-number" value="383"></td>,
 <td class="line-content"><span class="html-end-of-file"></span></td>]
```

As it can be seen it creates an two extra `td` elements, one with a class "line-number" and the other with the class "line-content" which has the actual html content of the site page within the `span` element. Is there a correct way to get this instead of in-between `&lt` and `&gt`?

**SOLVED**

I was saving it from the view page source. Instead I simply needed to save as.

Comment: Please either delete this or post an answer that will help future readers.

Comment: I thought my answer is there? Or do you mean I should answer my own question?

Comment: Answers should be posted as answers rather than as edits to the question. Ensure you include the relevant code to go with it. After 2 days you can accept your own answer to show it is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by using right-clicking the mouse on the page and then clicking "Save as.." (hotkey `Ctrl+s`) instead of right-clicking the mouse and then clicking "View page source" (hotkey `Ctrl+U`) which opened up the source page of the code.

So using the code;

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pathlib import Path


data_folder = Path("C:/Users/user/common/")
file_to_open = data_folder  / "mbh.html"
content = open(file_to_open)
content = content.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "lxml")
```

using `soup.find('div',{'class':'content'})` produced the correct results without the extra table elements;

```
In [5]: soup.find('div',{'id':'content'})
Out[5]: 
<div id="content">
<h1>Some content Header</h1>
<p class="info">Some info, many more elements</p>
```